# How do I train data in MATLAB in order to use in ANFIS?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, fuzzy-logic

I have `data = [a b c d]` and this data is in a loop, in which `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`'s values change.

```
for num=START:END
    [out1 out2] = some_funstion(input_image);
    a = out1+out2;
    b = out2-out1; %example
    data = [a b];
end
```

How can I save the whole data and train it?

Comment: could you give more details ? In each loop, does the data change according to a function or distribution ?

Comment: yeas,
I changed my postI want to save "data" that contains all a and b values;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code as the following:

```
data = [];
for num=START:END
    [out1 out2] = some_funstion(input_image);
    a = out1+out2;
    b = out2-out1;%example
    data = [data; a b]; % each row of data will be a and b
end

save('file.mat','data'); % save 'data' in the 'file.mat' file
load('file.mat'); % load 'data' from 'file.mat'.
```

By the way, in matlab, the comments are followed by '%'